# Best android data storage

Tags: android, json, sqlite

I'm new in android development and I'm planning to make simple dictionary app.
I'm looking for the best data storage for my dictionary.
I want is the more **faster** data storage. What is the best option should I use?

Answer (score -1):

A Directed Acyclic Word Graph (DAWG) is a very effecient way to store data for dictionary.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_word_graph